# Data modeling/forecasting in Python?

Tags: python, model, python-3.x, data-modeling

How do I go about this problem I've thought up? I don't even know if it's possible in [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29), but anyway. Basically, I want to give Python some data to look for patterns in the data and then display the most likely result. I thought pocket money would make a good example:

`A` gets $7 a week, a dollar a day, he spends $5 at the weekend and his balance on Monday is $2 + $1 ($7 a week 1 a day). This continues for three weeks. What will `A` get on the forth week?

```
Balance in account:  
week1 = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7  
week2 = 3,4,5,6,7,8,9  
week3 = 5,6,7,8,9,10,11  
week4 = ??????????
```

Now, instead of basic math I was wondering if it was possible to create a model, one that looks for patterns and then creates the data using the existing data and the patterns. So the script should be able to see that `A` gets $7 a week and he loses $5 a week. Is this possible?

Is the model possible to be flexible as in if I give it other data of the same nature, will it be able to find patterns?

(I'm using Python 3.2.)

Comment: Any Turing-complete problem is possible to be solved in any Turing-complete language. What is your question, exactly?

Comment: How exactly to i go about the problem, make the code spot the patterns then uses the patterns im quite a novice.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is classified as a regression problem.  Armed with this term, you should be able to find lots of information online and in books.

To point you in the right direction, I'd suggest investigating "linear regression" and perhaps moving on to a more complex regression model like the "random forests regressor".

The "scikit-learn" Python package has a number of different regression models and the documentation is excellent.